# I don't know why I get a segmentation fault in my code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

In the code I try to read a file, then I divide it with strtok to get the id of a directory (of 8 characters) and the kind of file I want to pass to the directory (A,B,C.pdf). Then I use the function system to execute the corresponding command. I know that in the txt file it comes first the id of the directory an after the type of file. I don't have any problem in the compilation, but when I execute the program, I get segmentation fault and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char ch, str[999], id[8], command[25];
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;
    char *pch;

    fp = fopen("p1.text", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){

        str[i] = ch;    
        i++;

    }
    pch = strtok(str, " ,.-\n");

    while(pch != NULL){
        if(isalpha(pch)){
            sprintf(command, "cp %s.pdf %s", pch, id);
            system(command);
            strcpy(command, "");
        }
        if(strlen(pch) == 8){
            strcpy(id, pch);
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ,.-\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find out where it segfaults

Comment: `if(strlen(pch) == 8){
            strcpy(id, pch);
        }` - `id` can't accommodate a string of length `8`. Mind the null-terminator.

Comment: You never check the length of anything you write into any of your arrays, are you sure those things are the correct size?

Comment: `id` isn't set the first time you call `sprintf(command, "cp %s.pdf %s", pch, id);`

Comment: You have several places where a segfault *could* be occuring, since you're not checking for buffer overflows anywhere and just trusting that the input is of the right size and format so that nothing will overflow. What are the contents of `p1.text`?

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @MikeHolt a group of ids (8 numbers), a letter and a number, after the number there is a \n:

05874121 A 7
07894544 C 3
55655454 B 5
05879544 B 6
75763465 C 2
05647236 A 8
05432124 A 9
05463726 B 10
05678080 B 6
05423123 C 2
05637234 C 4
05635642 A 4
05665756 B 9
05673824 C 10
05988288 B 5

Comment: @moinickcres What command do you want to run for each line?  For example, for the line `55655454 B 5` what command should be run?

Comment: @moinickcres Still. Use a debugger. You need to learn it sooner or later anyway.

Comment: @dbush for that it should be: cp B.pdf 55655454

Comment: `ch` should be an `int` as `EOF` is generally -1

Comment: @moinickcres Dude, people have helped you quite a bit here. Please reward them by upvoting and or accepting answers. It's how StackOverflow works. You get help, you provide reputation points to those as a thank you.

Comment: @moinickcres So you accepted an answer. Great! Did you learn anything from the answer I provided? As a software developer you are going to have to be able solve issues on your own, or learn how to debug your code and not just expect people to provide you with working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` variable isn't big enough to hold the value it needs to store.

Strings in C are null terminated.  So an 8 character string needs 9 bytes of storage.  `id` is only 8 elements long, so when you copy to it you write past the end of the array.  Writing outside the bounds of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case manifests in your code crashing.

Make `id` 9 elements long instead of 8:

```
int id[9];
```

You're also not storing the result of `fgetc` correctly.  You declare `ch` as a `char` but `fgetc` returns an `int`.  This is required to differentiate `EOF` from a normal character value.  So change the type of `ch` to `int`.

Also, you make things a bit more complicated than it needs to be by reading in the entire file at once and then having an internal state machine in your loop that calls `strtok` to figure out which element you're reading.

You can simplify this by reading in a line at a time with `fgets`, then calling `strtok` once to get `id` and once more to get `pch`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char line[100], command[100];
    FILE *fp;
    char *pch, *id;

    fp = fopen("p1.text", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        id = strtok(line, " \n");
        if (!id) continue;

        pch = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        if (!pch) continue;

        snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "cp %s.pdf %s", pch, id);
        //printf("command=%s\n", command);
        system(command);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show you a debugging process that you should learn so you can solve these issues on your own. The steps I took are shown below. Be aware that I'm not attempting to fix all possible problems with your code. I just isolated and fixed the initial problem.

You should get familiar with debugging tools such as `gdb` and `valigrind`. Sometimes running an executable under a debugger causes the problem to "go away". In those cases a memory access checking tool such as `valgrind` is very useful.

I ran your code with `valgrind` and it gave me the following output:

Before running `valgrind` you should build your executable with debug symbols. Assuming gcc you can follow the steps below.

```
jnorton@ubuntu:~/source$ gcc -ggdb fault.c 
jnorton@ubuntu:~/source$ ./a.out 
pch = this
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
jnorton@ubuntu:~/source$ clear

jnorton@ubuntu:~/source$ gcc -ggdb fault.c 
jnorton@ubuntu:~/source$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out
==6745== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6745== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6745== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6745== Command: ./a.out
==6745== 
pch = this
==6745== Invalid read of size 2
==6745==    at 0x108B25: main (fault.c:35)
==6745==  Address 0x2fda2c0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6745== 
==6745== 
==6745== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6745==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x2FDA2C0
==6745==    at 0x108B25: main (fault.c:35)
==6745==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6745==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6745==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6745==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6745==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==6745== 
==6745== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6745==     in use at exit: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
==6745==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 5,672 bytes allocated
==6745== 
==6745== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6745==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6745==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6745==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6745==    still reachable: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
==6745==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6745== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==6745== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==6745== 
==6745== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6745== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
jnorton@ubuntu:~/source$
```

Notice `valgrind` reported:

```
==6745==    at 0x108B25: main (fault.c:35)
```

I added some debug printfs, but line 35 is:

```
if(isalpha(pch)){
```

The `segfault` is happening here because `isalpha()` takes an `int` argument, not a pointer to a string. Changing that line to the following stops the `segfault`:

```
if(isalpha((int)pch[0])){
```

Now, that is only one problem in your code. You *may* have other issues.